# Background color and table in telegram bot message - how is it done?

Tags: telegram-bot

There is an example of formatting a message from a bot in a telegram (the bot's response to a request). The data in the form as shown in the screenshot is provided after clicking on the button on the left.

I just can’t find or at least roughly understand how such a design was done: background color, table. If someone has thoughts or guesses how to achieve the same result, then I send +100777 to karma :)

Tried via markup as HTML style

```
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
```

but nothing (((

[image: Bot response screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this was made with message fomatted as [MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style) with text inside ``` and ```.
This text would be with background and with monopace font.